# Count gif replays

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, animated-gif

Is it possible to count how many times an animated gif has played with javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible.

However, you could create an interval using `setInterval` with the duration of the animation which increases a counter.

Comment: it's as close as you'll get with a GIF anim, but it's no good enough because you can't set it going at the moment when the image starts animating.

Comment: nor can you predict how fast the browser will actually animate said GIF

Comment: @Moiblpadde instead of 'thanks anyway' click the green checkmark to give ThiefMaster credit for the answer.

Comment: He'll have to wait 10 more minutes to do so.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Just a few sec faster than me :D

Answer (score 3):

As @ThiefMaster says, You can't do this with a GIF anim.

However, you can achieve what you want using a javascript animation.

Rather than saving the frames of the animation in a GIF anim, save them in a single PNG file, in a row (ie so it looks like a reel of film) either horizontally or vertically.

Display the image in an element on the page that is sized so you can only see one frame of the animation at a time, and then use Javascript to adjust the CSS offset of the image at regular intervals using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

This technique is known as CSS Sprite animations. It's easy to do, and it's basically the standard way of doing spot graphic animations on the web now (GIF anims are *soooo* 1998).

Google will give you plenty of resources to help you find out more: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+sprite+animations

You might also want to read the accepted answer to this question: [Why not animated GIF instead of animated CSS sprites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186257/why-not-animated-gif-instead-of-animated-css-sprites)

Comment: Don't forget about SVG animations, which can use javascript directly on the SVG DOM, but also support a declarative style. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html

Comment: @sehe - good point. However for this question I'd stick with CSS sprites, as they'll be easier to convert from an existing animGIF.